# XNA C# calling functions from other classes with Lists

Tags: c#, list, xna-4.0

I am trying to call a 'shoot laser' function, which is in my ProjectileManager Class, from my Player class controls.

Thing is, when I call the exact same function from either my ProjectileManager or the Game1 (main game) class - it works. otherwise I am getting a null on the sprite.

I am doing a content.load on the sprite in projectilemanager class, which works fine when i call the shoot laser function from either the projectilemanager itself or the main game - but not the player class?

note: ive cut out alot of pointless additional functions within these classes for readability

**Game1 Class**

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
// CLASSES
Player myPlayer;
ProjectileManager projectileManager = new ProjectileManager();


protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    projectileManager.ContentLoad(Content);
}


protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.V)) //SHOOT LASER TEST - WORKS
    {
        projectileManager.ShootLaser(new Vector2(5, 5), 5, 1, new Vector2(0, 0), 0, 0);
    }

    myPlayer.Update();
    projectileManager.Update();

    base.Update(gameTime);
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
    GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = noFilter;
    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null);


    myPlayer.Draw(spriteBatch);
    projectileManager.Draw(spriteBatch);


    spriteBatch.End();
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
}
```

**Player Class**

```
class Player
{   

    // Inherent classes
    ProjectileManager projectileManager = new ProjectileManager();

    Texture2D sprite;
    public Vector2 direction;
    float speed;
    float health;
    int spriteType;

    public void Update()
    {

        UpdateControls();

    }


    void UpdateControls()
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) //SHOOT LASER - DOESNT WORK
        {
            projectileManager.ShootLaser(new Vector2(5, 5), 5, 1, new Vector2(0, 0), 0, 0);
        }

    }

}
```

**Projectile Manager Class**

```
    class ProjectileManager
{
    //Lists
    List<Projectile> projectiles = new List<Projectile>();

    //Sprites
    Texture2D sprite;
    Texture2D spriteLaser;

    //Attributes
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 dimensions;
    int attackPower;
    int moveType; //0 = direction based, 1 = homing on player, 3 = hybrid of both (like a missile that fires straight then turns towards target
    int team; //the team that the laser is on for collision
    Vector2 direction;
    float speed;



    public ProjectileManager(){}

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.E))
        {
            ShootLaser(new Vector2(5,5), 5, 1, new Vector2(0,0), 0, 0);
        }

        foreach (Projectile each in projectiles)
        {
            each.Update();
        }
    }

    public void ContentLoad(ContentManager content)
    {
        spriteLaser = content.Load<Texture2D>("playerLaser");
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch)
    {
        foreach (Projectile each in projectiles)
        {
            each.Draw(spritebatch);
        }
    }

   public void ShootLaser (Vector2 a_position, int a_attackPower, float a_speed, Vector2 a_direction, int a_moveType, int a_team)
   {
       position = a_position;
       attackPower = a_attackPower;
       speed = a_speed;
       direction = a_direction;
       moveType = a_moveType;
       team = a_team;

       projectiles.Add(new Projectile(spriteLaser, position, 5, 2, new Vector2(0,1), 0, 0));
   }

}
```

**projectile class**

```
    class Projectile
{
    Vector2 position;
    int attackPower;
    int moveType; //0 = direction based, 1 = homing on player, 3 = hybrid of both (like a missile that fires straight then turns towards target
    int team; //the team that the laser is on for collision
    Texture2D sprite;

    Vector2 direction;
    float speed;

    public Projectile(Texture2D a_sprite, Vector2 a_position, int a_attackPower, float a_speed, Vector2 a_direction, int a_moveType, int a_team) //possibly add another variable for hitting other projetiles / cancelling them out
    {
        sprite = a_sprite;
        position = a_position;
        attackPower = a_attackPower;
        speed = a_speed;
        direction = a_direction;
        moveType = a_moveType;
        team = a_team;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        //movement
        // if movetype = 1
        if (moveType == 0) // straight line
        {
            position.Y++;
            //position += direction * speed;
        }

    }

    //public Rectangle GetRectangle()
    //{
    //    return new Rectangle((int)m_position.X, (int)m_position.Y, (int)m_dimensions.X, (int)m_dimensions.Y);
    //}

    // We pass-in a 'SpriteBatch' object so this function
    // can call the 'Draw' function on it.
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch)
    {
        spritebatch.Draw(sprite, position, Color.White);
    }

}
```

Ive just started learning C#, I cant find any reference to why in the game and projectile manager classes the shootlaser function works, but calling from the player yields no results.

ive tried to debug using breakpoints and from what I can gather the projectile Texture2D sprite is returning a null when the function is called through the player class..

Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: http://speedy.sh/RedMH/PIXLSPODE.zip

here is the c# xna project, bout 84kb of bad coding but if it helps

Comment: that site looks shady. you should just start a [github](https://github.com/) account and share a link.

Comment: https://github.com/bswinbanks/PIXLSPLODE_

done and done :)

Comment: awesome will check out

Comment: im beginning to think ive run into a bug. going to reinstall c# express because i cant explain why its works for one class and not another as i have literally copied the code over and it wont work :(

(the test shoot inside spawner.cs works fine but doesnt in player.cs - sprite keeps returning a NULL)

Comment: I thought I fixed your shooting from the player class thing? what happened?

Comment: can I have a look at the code you used yeah it still doesnt work. the sprite batch returns a null when ran through player but not through other classes. I am calling content load exactly the same in both its really strange. reinstalling C# it might be a bug i cant explain it

Comment: https://github.com/bswinbanks/PIXLSPLODE_/

commited latest changes :( this is so frustrating thanks man

Comment: Have you taken down your github for it I was trying to see what changes you made earlier

Comment: will put it back up after work. I did a few more things to tinker so the code has the bullets coming from the player model shooting up. looks cool. And my son loves the retro look.

Comment: oh brilliant thanks.

yeah that was the next thing to do just that shooting issue was like a mental block i didnt want to do anything else since it worked. keen to see what it was to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ContentLoad` method to your `Player` class and call the `projectileManager.ContentLoad` there then call `myPlayer.ContentLoad` in `Game1.LoadContent` Method

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
// CLASSES
Player myPlayer;



protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    myPlayer.ContentLoad(CoolContent);
}
```

player class:

```
class Player
{   

// Inherent classes
ProjectileManager projectileManager = new ProjectileManager();

Texture2D sprite;
public Vector2 direction;
float speed;
float health;
int spriteType;

public void LoadContent(CoolContentType coolContent)
{
    projectileManager.LoadContent(coolContent);
}

public void Update()
{

    UpdateControls();

}
```

in addition to linking your `ContentLoad` Method calls. you should get rid of the `Texture2D` in the `Projectile` class because it is redundant.

all you need is the values from the Projectiles in your `Draw` calls while `ProjectileManager` stores the texture.

```
class ProjectileManager
{
//Lists
List<Projectile> projectiles = new List<Projectile>();

//Sprites
Texture2D sprite;
Texture2D spriteLaser;

//Attributes
Vector2 position;
Vector2 dimensions;
int attackPower;
int moveType; //0 = direction based, 1 = homing on player, 3 = hybrid of both (like a missile that fires straight then turns towards target
int team; //the team that the laser is on for collision
Vector2 direction;
float speed;



public ProjectileManager(){}

public void Update()
{
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.E))
    {
        ShootLaser(new Vector2(5,5), 5, 1, new Vector2(0,0), 0, 0);
    }

    foreach (Projectile each in projectiles)
    {
        each.Update();
    }
}

public void ContentLoad(ContentManager content)
{
    spriteLaser = content.Load<Texture2D>("playerLaser");
}

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch)
{
    spritebatch.Begin();

    foreach (Projectile p in projectiles)
    {
        spritebatch.draw(spriteLaser, p.position,Color.CoolColor);//see how I use the projectile info (p.position).  it doesn't need it's own texture :)
    }

    spritebatch.End();
}
```

Comment: Tried this just now, by adding breakpoints I can see that the update and draw methods on the projectile class don't even run when i use the Player class controls.

Comment: http://speedy.sh/RedMH/PIXLSPODE.zip

if anyone wants to have a quick look at the issue

Comment: Thankyou,

The reason I have the texture2D inside the projectile itself is because later down the track I am going to be having multiple types of bullets / lasers and want to define them in the list so all my bullets are handled in the one list.

Adding ContentLoad to the player did not solve the problem, it seems that the update and draw methods arent even initialising when I use the player class 'shoot' function.

and to further clarify, its sort of important I get this one working as I will use the same fix to get my enemy AI to shoot independently

Comment: @Swinny put all your different bullet textures into a Dictionary<Enum,Texture2D> in the ProjectileManager. this will make managing the projectiles easier and they are still dynamic. and projectile would carry an Enum that the manager would test for when drawing . don't worry Dictionaries are fast.

Comment: Oh sweet ill look into dictionaries when I get home from work!

After checking your changes, the laser still wouldnt fire on the spacebar command??

The original problem still exists - was it working for you? thanks

Comment: @Swinny oh I thought it was the "G" key under player update. I'll check for a place where spacebar is used.

Comment: oh either way, I just put one in the player update and in the update controls function to see if that was a problem, but yes neither were working on the last version i checked?

they should effectively be doing what happens when you press 'v'

which is the same call coming from the projectileManager class ( except as you know we want to call it from player for house-keeping.) also this problem has me scartching my head in general